How to avoid query Cosmos DB for documents to process in a way that avoids hot partitions?
We have a monthly job that updates documents in our Cosmos DB and updates them:

Document schema:

id - The document ID. It's a random GUID
userId - The partition key. It's also random GUID
balance - a number that the monthly job sets to zero
balanceExpiry - the month and year when the balance should be set to zero by the monthly job

And here is the cross-partition query:
SELECT c.userId FROM c WHERE c.balanceExpiry = @TheCurrentMonthAndYear AND c.balance > 0
This monthly job causes hot partitions because the documents returned by .Net Cosmos DB SDK is sorted by partition key range. Here how the response looks like:

Document 1 in partition key range 1
Document 2 in partition key range 1
Repeat for thousands of documents in partition key range 1
Document 3 in partition key range 2
Document 4 in partition key range 2
Repeat for thousands of documents in partition key range 2
And so on

The problem with the documents being sorted by partition, is the partition becomes hot when multiple "Updater" instances concurrency process the messages in the queue because all update operations are in the same physical partition.
I tried to find ways to randomize the order of the documents such as adjusting MaxConcurrency, but nothing worked. Adding an ORDER BY clause to the query also didn't work because it either maxed out the Container's RUs or caused the query to be very slow.
Is there a solution that does not involve querying another data source, changing the partition key, or introducing a random visibility to the queue message?

It's not really clear what your issue is, as you're describing things without specifics. Please edit to show exact details such as container partition choice, sample data, example query/queries, etc (a [mcve]). Also, fyi - you can't just "avoid" a hot partition (you can't re-partition without re-creating a container).

Thanks for your input. I have added more details to my post. I know that I can't re-partition without creating a new container. I'm just hoping that there is a simple solution that I'm missing.
